# How can I authenticate in a generic way using a username and password to an OAuth SSO in a spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm creating an app that will serve as kind of an anticorruption layer. As such I will need to authenticate to an SSO (here Keycloak) using a predefined (configured) username and password. This will provide me with a token that my legacy application will accept.

I would like to do this in a generic enough way (meaning to **not** just do a hard coded POST to the Keycloak endpoint as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65220747/how-can-i-make-my-spring-boot-application-to-log-in-to-keycloak-with-given-usern)) maybe by just pointing to the `.well-known/openid-configuration` and then have some comprehensible enough code to retrieve the `access_token`, `refresh_token` and then be able to refresh the `access_token` when it's about to expire.

I seem to be unable to find a proper full backend example but this seems like something that should be existing for ages now. I guess I'm probably just not using the right keywords.

Please note that I have no frontend at all here. Everything is triggered on the backend by received events.

Thank you